# How to use qmllint in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qt5, qmllint

[qmllint](http://www.kdab.com/kdab-contributions-qt-5-4-qmllint/) is a syntax checker for QML files written by KDAB which is shipped as a plugin with Qt 5.4. It's usage is based on command line like:

```
$ qmllint myFile.qml
```

Is it possible to use it directly in Qt Creator?

Comment: Could you manage it via the QtCreator gui? Also, when and how exactly do you want to run it, at which stage, what process, etc, or my explanation is OK? I was trying to mention the possible scenarios as your question is a bit vague in that sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## QtCreator

You can actually set custom commands in QtCreator to be run without cluttering your qmake file manually because that will effect all the other people in your project, too.

So, if you want to make sure that you only do it for yourself and not clutter it for others, using QtCreator's shiny GUI, I would suggest to follow this:

- Projects (left pane)
- Build & Run
- Build Steps
- Add Build Step

Here is the screen how exactly you can set up the command with the corresponding arguments:

[image]

With QtCreator's GUI, you can easily change the order with the same concept without touching your project file should you prefer that. There are use cases for that like:

- You would not want to run any steps, not even qmake, before the qml file is properly validated
- You only have C++ files, so there is no such a thing as "linkage".
- etc.

## qmake

There are other "generic" approaches useful outside QtCreator, although you asked about this IDE, like putting the command into variables like:

- [QMAKE_PRE_LINK](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-pre-link)

  ```
  QMAKE_PRE_LINK = qmllint $$PWD/path/to/myFile.qml
  ```
- [QMAKE_POST_LINK](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-post-link)

  ```
  QMAKE_POST_LINK = qmllint $$PWD/path/to/myFile.qml
  ```
- System command execution from your qmake project file

  ```
  system("qmllint $$PWD/path/to/myFile.ml")
  ```
- [Adding custom targets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) with [QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-extra-targets)

  ```
  qmllinttarget.commands = qmllint $$PWD/path/to/myFile.qml
  QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += qmllinttarget
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the point in this question is *not* to have a check for a single file with known name, but to run qmllint on all qml files of a project. Ideally this should be done before building anything, because a build with erroneous qml files is likely to have no real value.

Extending lpapp's answer and playing around with qmake a bit, I came to this solution:

```
ALL_PWD_QML_FILES = $$files($${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/*.qml , true)

# a command that creates an empty file with a given name.
win32 {
    MY_TOUCH_CMD = copy NUL
} else {
    MY_TOUCH_CMD = touch
}

qmllint.output = .qmllint/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.qmllint
qmllint.input = ALL_PWD_QML_FILES
qmllint.commands = qmllint ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} && $${MY_TOUCH_CMD} ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
qmllint.CONFIG += no_link recursive target_predeps

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += qmllint
```

This assumes that all qml files are either in the same directory as the .pro file or in subdirectories.

It will run qmllint on all qml files before the actual build, but only if any qml file has changed since a previous build.

Tested on Windows with Qt 5.11 and MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QMAKE_POST_LINK` variable in your .pro file like :

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK = qmllint $$PWD/QMLFiles/myFile.qml
```

This runs qmllint on your QML file when you build your project.